# how to disable angular cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

I have **two function in controller that are connected to two checkboxes in view**. The problem is that every time I **do any change in these functions it is not detected by the browser**. I even went and removed both of the functions completely and the browser behaved as if they were still there. This is happening in all firefox and chrome

I did some research online and seems to me that this is problem of angular caching templates. I do `use ui-router` but so far

**I have removed my browser cache it did'nt solve the problem**

**I added this code but nothing seems to help**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
```

My code:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
            <label class='checkboxes' id='checkbox_1'>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="thirtyDay" ng-change="changeAxis1()">
            Last 30 days
            </label>
             <label class='checkboxes' id='checkbox_2'>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="wholeTimeline" ng-change="changeAxis2()">
            Election timeline
            </label>
             </div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.wholeTimeline = true;

         $scope.changeAxis2 = function() {
                if($scope.wholeTimeline) {
                        $scope.thirtyDay = false;

                        alert('is checked')

                    } else {
                    alert('is unchecked')
                    }
        };



        $scope.changeAxis1 = function() {
            if ($scope.thirtyDay) {
                        $scope.wholeTimeline = false;
                        alert('is checked')

                    }else {
                    alert('is unchecked')
                    }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using anonymous/incognito mode both in firefox/chrome.

According to this the cache is never used in that mode:
https://www.quora.com/Does-incognito-mode-on-Chrome-use-the-cache-that-was-previously-stored